# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined rarely happening

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I've been creating a tool, and needed to create a series of dropdown menus to select a profile/view id (from google analytics) that populates the next menu on change of the previous one (selecting the correct properties for the correct accounts, and then the correct profiles for the correct properties).

To this end I made a small jquery/javascript for loop system which I think is actually quite messy but am not sure on how to improve on it (not part of the question though, but this could be one of the reasons I'm having the problem, although I'm not sure).

This script works across all the browsers I've tested, including mobile devices which I was really happy about.

However, when the tool was launched, two people (out of about a hundred) came back saying that the profile/view hadn't been selected. Which was very curious, since I couldn't replicate this error.

I had been in contact with one of the people and tried debugging (albeit a slow process through long series of meetings etc), but couldn't find a fix for it, (although I think I managed to isolate the problem, which will be pointed out after the code sample).

So my question is this. What could be causing this length of undefined error, and why is it only happening for 1-2 people out of a large sum of them (appears to be in jquery.min.js:2 using jquery version 1.11.1?). The error seems to be occuring when the property is changed, which is strange since the profiles are filling out correctly. Also I asked if the client could use different browsers and accounts but the same error kept happening.

Here is the code that creates the dropdowns:

```
    function fillDropdownMenus(){

        var accounts = <?php echo json_encode($accountsArray); ?>;

        var propertiesSelectHtml = '<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 properties"><select class="col-xs-12" id="properties"><option selected="selected">PROPERTY NAMES</option></select></div>';
        var profilesSelectHtml = '<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 profiles"><select class="col-xs-12" id="profiles"><option selected="selected">VIEW NAMES</option></select></div>';

        accounts.forEach(function(account){

            var accountIterator = 0;
            account.account['id'].forEach(function(accountId){
                $('#accounts').append('<option value="'+accountId+'">'+account.account['name'][accountIterator]+'</option>');
                accountIterator++;
            });

        });

        $('.accounts').on('change','#accounts', function(event){

            var currentAccount = $('#accounts').val();

            $('.properties').remove();

            $('.profiles').remove();

            $('.accounts').after(propertiesSelectHtml);

            accounts.forEach(function(account){
                $.each(account.account, function(accountkey, accountvalue){
                    if(accountvalue == currentAccount){
                        var propertyIterator = 0;

                        account.account['property']['id'].forEach(function(propertyId){
                            $('#properties').append('<option value="'+propertyId+'">'+account.account['property']['name'][propertyIterator]+'</option>');
                            propertyIterator++;
                        });
                    }
                });
            });

            $('.properties').on('change','#properties', function(ev){

                var currentProperty = $('#properties').val();

                $('.profiles').remove();

                $('.properties').after(profilesSelectHtml);

                accounts.forEach(function(account){
                    $.each(account.account['property'], function(propertykey, propertyvalues){
                        if($.type(propertyvalues) == 'object' || $.type(propertyvalues) == 'array'){
                            for(var k in propertyvalues){
                                var propertyvalue = propertyvalues[k];

                                if(propertyvalue == currentProperty){
                                    var profileIterator = 0;

                                    account.account['property']['profile']['id'].forEach(function(profileId){
                                        $('#profiles').append('<option value="'+profileId+'">'+account.account['property']['profile']['name'][profileIterator]+'</option>');
                                        profileIterator++;
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            if(propertyvalue == currentProperty){
                                var profileIterator = 0;
                                account.account['property']['profile']['id'].forEach(function(profileId){
                                    $('#profiles').append('<option value="'+profileId+'">'+account.account['property']['profile']['name'][profileIterator]+'</option>');
                                    profileIterator++;
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });

                $('#profiles').on('change', function(e){

                    $('#view_id').removeAttr('value');

                    var currentProfile = $('#profiles').val();

                    $('#view_id').val(currentProfile);

                });

            });

        });

    }

    fillDropdownMenus();
```

And the object structure:

```
Object -> account (object) -> id (array)
                           -> name (array)
                           -> property (object) -> id (array)
                                                -> name (array)
                                                -> profile (object) -> id (array)
                                                                    -> name (array)
```

Thank you for your input on this issue of mine as I've been bashing my head against the wall for a couple of days trying to figure this out!

EDIT: http://codepen.io/zephyr/pen/VYQPKQ Here's a codepen of the list in action.

Comment: var accounts = <?php echo json_encode($accountsArray); ?>; Should you not do var accounts = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($accountsArray); ?>');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appeared to be an error in my javascript being very inconsistent (having so many different for loops was not helping). After I changed them all to the normal .each jquery loop it seemed to fix the problem, and made the whole menu set work much better, as there were some logical errors as well (I wasn't filtering the profiles by property, it was just displaying them all for that account when the property was selected).